# android studio AFATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0

Tags: android, exception

**code:**

08-03 20:11:10.513 26273-26306/com.example.admin.blue E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
08-03 20:11:10.513 26273-26306/com.example.admin.blue E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.admin.blue, PID: 26273
08-03 20:11:10.513 26273-26306/com.example.admin.blue E/AndroidRuntime: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
08-03 20:11:10.513 26273-26306/com.example.admin.blue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6072)
08-03 20:11:10.513 26273-26306/com.example.admin.blue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:861)
08-03 20:11:10.513 26273-26306/com.example.admin.blue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16459)
08-03 20:11:10.513 26273-26306/com.example.admin.blue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16459)
08-03 20:11:10.513 26273-26306/com.example.admin.blue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16459)
08-03 20:11:10.513 26273-26306/com.example.admin.blue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16459)
08-03 20:11:10.513 26273-26306/com.example.admin.blue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16459)
08-03 20:11:10.513 26273-26306/com.example.admin.blue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16459)
08-03 20:11:10.513 26273-26306/com.example.admin.blue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:352)
08-03 20:11:10.513 26273-26306/com.example.admin.blue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16459)
08-03 20:11:10.513 26273-26306/com.example.admin.blue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6607)
08-03 20:11:10.513 26273-26306/com.example.admin.blue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3820)
08-03 20:11:10.513 26273-26306/com.example.admin.blue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3678)
08-03 20:11:10.513 26273-26306/com.example.admin.blue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3653)
08-03 20:11:10.513 26273-26306/com.example.admin.blue E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.admin.blue.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:56)
08-03 20:11:10.513 26273-26306/com.example.admin.blue E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)

**Please help me find out what is causing problems with AFATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0**

**Thank you very much~**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access views from threads. 
Once you are detached from your View, Fragment, Activity (whatever), you can only access some views on your original "parent".

Please, provide some more information from where are you trying to access it.
You could probably solve this by working on AsyncTask or using run on UI threads.